# When I try to start lampp the terminal says that it only works on 32bit

Tags: php, lamp, xampp

I already have the ia32-libs installed and i used this code

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

anyone have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That depends entirely on what it actually is that you are doing, which you haven't described.

Comment: @psusi  This already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LAMP is a software bundle for Linux that includes Apache, MYSQL, and PHP.

To install LAMP you need to do the following:

*install apache*:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

*Optional:* Testing Lamp:
`http://localhost/` in your browser

*install and restart Apache*:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

*Test PHP if you like:*

In the terminal copy/paste the following line:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/testphp.php
```

This will open up a file called phptest.php.

Step 2. Copy/Paste this line into the phptest file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Step 3. Save and close the file.

Step 4. Now open you're web browser and type the following into the web address:

```
http://localhost/testphp.php
```

*Install MYSQL:*

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

gksudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Change the line
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to your local IP. This will enable other computers on your network to see this computer, this step is optional.

This is where things may start to get tricky. Begin by typing the following into Terminal:

```
mysql -u root
```

*Set root password*

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

(Make sure to change yourpassword to a password of your choice.)

*Install phpMyAdmin which is an easy tool to edit your databases. Copy/paste the following line into Terminal:*

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

*Make PHP play nice with each other:*

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Now we are going to have to uncomment the following line by taking out the semicolon (;).

*Change this line:*

```
;extension=mysql.so
```

To look like this:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

*Restart Apache one last time*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```